# Calculate the Fourier coefficients of $g(x)=\pi f'(x+2009)$

Tags: fourier-analysis

> Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ be a $2\pi -$periodic and continuously differentiable function such that $\hat f(n)=3^{-n^2}$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z},$ where $\hat f(n)$ is the $n-$th Fourier coefficient.
>
> Calculate the Fourier coefficients of $g(x)=\pi f'(x+2009)$

My attempt:

We know the following in general:

$1) \ \hat h'(n)=in \hat h(n)$

$2) \ \hat h(c+x)=e^{inc}\hat h(n), c\in \mathbb{R}$

In our case:

$\hat f'(n)=in\hat f(n)=in3^{-n^2}$

For $t(x)=f'(x+2009): \hat t(n)=e^{in2009}in3^{-n^2}$

So $\hat g(n)=\pi e^{in2009}in3^{-n^2}$

Is my solution correct?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is absolutely correct. If you want more control on what's going on,
you can define some notations:

$$\begin{array}{rcll}{C}_{n} \left(f\right)&=&\widehat{f} \left(n\right)&\text{the fourier coefficient}\\
D \left(f\right)&=&{f'}&\text{the derivation operator}\\
{L}_{c} \left(f\right) \left(x\right)&=&f \left(x+c\right)&\text{the left translation operator}
\end{array}$$

Then the rules are

$$\begin{array}{rcl}{C}_{n} \left(D \left(f\right)\right)&=&i n {C}_{n} \left(f\right)\\
{C}_{n} \left({L}_{c} \left(f\right)\right)&=&{e}^{i n c} {C}_{n} \left(f\right)
\end{array}$$

Now you have $g = {\pi} {L}_{2009} \left(D \left(f\right)\right)$. The rules give

$$\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}  \begin{array}{rcl}{C}_{n} \left(g\right)&=&{\pi} {C}_{n} \left({L}_{2009} \left(D \left(f\right)\right)\right)\\
&=&{\pi} {e}^{i 2009 n} {C}_{n} \left(D \left(f\right)\right)\\
&=&{\pi} {e}^{i 2009 n} i n {C}_{n} \left(f\right)\\
&=&{\pi} {e}^{i 2009 n} i n {3}^{{-{n}^{2}}}
\end{array}$$